# Problema no Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio

Olá Estou tendo problemas para baixar as extenções do Android Studio [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique se os pacotes foram atualizados, pois as vezes comigo também acontece isso, mas os pacotes são atualizados.

Comment: como eu verifico os pacotes ?

Comment: Na tala do Android SDK Manager mostra na coluna status "Installed" para cada pacote instalado. :)

Comment: Se eu desisntalar tudo e reinstalar dá certo ?

Comment: Apenas verifique se os pacotes que foi solicitado para instalação estão instalado.